# How to Tabbar Show in Another Sidemenu item?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, side-menu

Why my Tabbar Show in Another Sidemenu item, here is my code

```
let navigate = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(navigate, animated: true)
```

Comment: What is "Another Sidemenu item"? Please share some more code.

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this you have to add navigation controller before making root view controller from tabbar like shown in image. Then it will shown to your another controller.

[image]